# Can the SLA fields Violation, Elapsed Time be shown up top at the case level

Tags: case, casemilestone, entitlements

I am working on the OOTB Entitlement and Milestones. I want to show Milestones fields at the Case level like Violation, Elapsed Time and Target Response etc.

Can the key Milestone fields Violation, Elapsed Time and Target Response be shown up top at the case level?

I dont see the option that you're saying:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Case is related with Milestones through Entitlement. So, you can show the Entitlement Record on Case level, but Milestones records cannot be displayed at Case level at least through formula fields.

You can create custom fields at Case and from apex coding populate those values from Milestones. But a Case can have multiple milestones. So you need to think which milestone record to be shown on Case level.

**Update based on comments**

When the milestone is violated you can define workflow field update action to update a Case field.

To define this:

> Go to Entitlement Process --> Milestone --> Violation Action

**Add time trigger: 1 Minute After**

[image: Milestone status violation]

Comment: that can be done by workflow field update, check my ans

Comment: that can be done through trigger, post a separate question

Comment: That you can check at milestone record

Answer (score 0):

The OOTB `Milestone Status Icon`, `Milestone Status` can be shown on the Case Detailed page. You can not show ElapseTime and Target Response Time, since multiple milestone could run on a single case simultaneously.

[image]

In order to show the Total ElapseTime of the completed Milestone, need to query over the CaseMilestones and write the logic using controller.